# Best Load testing tool for asp.net 3.5 IIS6.0 WITH vs 2008 Professional Edition

Tags: asp.net, load-testing

Hi i would like to know best testing tool for asp.net website which can run with VS 2008 Professional Edition.
I would like to do
Load Testing
Stress Testing

Also i would like to calculate Concurrent users count that can access my website.

There are many tools available, but i am not able to judge best one.

If anybody knoes then please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this but there is [WebAII](http://www.artoftest.com/products/webaii.aspx), a free UI test engine for .Net.  Telerik supports this testing framework as well.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this depends on your infrastructure. If you have a lot of computers available to simulate a multi user environment you can use [OpenSTA](http://opensta.org/). I've tried a lot of tools and i'm finally landed on [Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). It is easy to install and to use.

There is also a companion tool that can be used to generate test scripts for JMeter: [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, Does All the tools you have mentioned is for ASP.NET ?

Comment: You can Test every web site with this tools. They make a http request and measure the results. Of corse this works with ASP.NET too

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Web Application Stress Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313559) from Microsoft.

Comment: @PhilPursglove: The "Web Application Stress Tool" is broken.

Comment: Looks like it's been replaced by the Web Capacity Analysis Tool - http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Visual Studio Team System Test Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182409.aspx).

Have used the [test types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182514.aspx) load testing and web testing.
Worked very well.